# How Many Tattoos Does the Main Character in 'Memento' Have?

Tags: character, memento

I recently watched the movie *Memento* and was intrigued by the use of tattoos as a key plot device. Leonard Shelby, the main character, uses tattoos as a way to remember crucial information due to his anterograde amnesia.

I'm curious to know the number of tattoos he has throughout the film.

Comment: The downvotes are probably from the lack of research.  The answers to this (full lists of the tattoos) are extremely easy to find.

Comment: @iandotkelly - can you point to one of those lists that meets the standards of this site? That is to say, properly referenced.

Comment: If someone put a list of the tattoos on this site and said "from my own watching of the movie" or "my own research" people would find that acceptable.  Properly referenced is an ideal, not a requirement.   I'm not saying the question is invalid or off-topic, just trying to explain to the OP why he might be getting downvotes.

Comment: @iandotkelly - Not all of the tattoos are visible or clear in the film. I've not been able to find clear pictures of all of them or even any behind-the-scenes shots that show them clearly. I think this is an example of a question that would be **easy to answer poorly, but difficult to answer well.**

Answer (score 1):

According to [Shmoop](https://www.shmoop.com/study-guides/memento/tattoos-symbol.html), Leonard has 26 tattoos (I'm counting the 1st tattoo in their list as 2 separate tattoos).

A related [answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/8401/67819) lists some of the tattoos, but not all of them.

A social media post from [CinemaGrids](https://twitter.com/CinemaGrids/status/1121966847732011008) shows around half of Leonard's tattoos.